# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on socket io with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using node js, expressjs, socketio, redis with Django.

## Node server:

```
const PORT = 8008;
const HOST = 'localhost';

var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app);

var app = express();

const redis = require('redis');

log('info', 'connected to redis server');

const io = require('socket.io');

if (!module.parent) {
    server.listen(PORT, HOST);
    const socket = io.listen(server);

    socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        const subscribe = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1')
        subscribe.subscribe('test');

        subscribe.on("message", function(pattern, channel, message) {
            client.send(channel, message);
            log('msg', "received from channel #" + channel + " : " + message);
        });

    });
```

## Client:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8008/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8008/");

      socket.on('connect', function(data){
        socket.emit('subscribe', {channel:'test'});
      });


      socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('received a message: ', data);

      });
```

Server is sending message to the channel but when it's loading on the client,I get the following error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8008/socket.io/1/?t=1399898337175. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Answer (score 7):

You can also configure your socket server to enable wildcard origins.

```
io.configure('development', function(){
    io.set('origins', '*:*');
}
```

Or

```
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Check https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO for more

Comment: I was getting the same error, but it seems I was using the external ip to hit the site, but 'localhost' in `io.connect...`. Using the same for both fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable cors on server side.

add this in your node code

```
// Enables CORS
var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, *');

        // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    };
};

app.configure(function() {
    // enable CORS!
    app.use(enableCORS);

});
```

Comment: `io.set` returns this error `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'` and the below one says `TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  } has no method 'configure'`

Comment: Yes the second options throws `TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) { app.handle(req, res, next); } has no method 'configure' `